# Pretty URL using laravel 4.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I'm creating a website using Laravel (first time user) and I have managed to have URL's such as

```
localhost/branch/pass
```

so without using the .php at the end of pass. But what I'm trying to achieve is this, when a user visits the 'pass' page they should take a token with them which is sent via email so they should visit it like this...

```
localhost/branch/pass?token=blah
```

what I want the URL to look like is...

```
localhost/branch/pass/blah
```

I've achieved this before in .htaccess while NOT using laravel I was just wondering if laravel had their own way of doing this or will it be the same as I've previously done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Routes` file, we can filter for dynamic properties using `{}` in the path. Being that this is a `GET` request, we can just use `Route::get`.

```
Route::get('branch/pass/{token}', 'MyController@MyFunction');
```

Then you can properly make your URL's in the email like:

```
http://localhost/branch/pass/blah
```

and the `blah` which is your token, will be passed as an argument to the function you declared within your controller.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any need to modify your .htaccess files to do this with Laravel as it will all be handled internally.

Create your route.

```
Route::get('branch/pass/{token}', array('uses' => 'YourController@yourFunction', 'as' => 'passwordRoute'));
```

One thing to note here is I named the route to `passwordRoute`.  You can change the name to whatever you want.  I find this very useful because in the future if you need to make changes to the route, as long as the name stays the same, you will always be able to find it by its name.

Create your function which you probably already have somewhere.

```
class YourController extends BaseClass {

    public function yourFunction($token)
    {
        // Do stuff with your token.
    }
}
```

Now you can create urls to this route very easily by using `URL::route()` and passing in the route's name.

```
URL::route('passwordRoute', array('token' => $token));
```

Here, we are calling the route by it's name we already defined.  This will grab the route, see that the route needs a parameter for a `token`, and then replace that `token` parameter with whatever is stored in your `$token` variable.  Of course, your variable might be different you may need to change `$token` to whatever variable you are using to store the actual token.

In your case, it would be whatever variable is set to `blah`.

This function will then output the URL which you are looking for based on the route and the parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a couple of questions... 1) Where does passwordRoute come from? Or is it a custom name? 2) Where do I put the last URL::route? Because it keeps telling me $token is undefined when I put it where I'd have assumed

Comment: Sorry, should have explained further.  I updated the answer to hopefully explain it a bit better.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot more sense, however $token is still 'undefined' even though it's the only variable I have used. Also I have a feeling that on the Route::get where I have 'uses' => 'PassController@getToken' (that's my function name) inside the PassController, it's not going to the function and doing anything in it but I can now access branch/pass/token_string

Comment: Ignore that last comment, it is going to the function but $token is still empty

Comment: What does your URL look like?  The token should be in there.

Comment: It says branch/pass/token but when I try to use it, the $token is empty I must be doing something wrong